# Laravel 7 Policy not working (or not registered) using Sanctum with Vue SPA

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

Laravel Policy is not being registered. Even if the Policy denies all abilities any authenticated user is being able to perform any action on any resource.

Policy example:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Tag;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class TagPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;
    /* BELOW EVERYTHING RETURNS FALSE FOR DEBUGGING PURPOSES*/
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return false;
    }
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return false;
    }
    /* other methods .... */
}
```

I tried to register the Policies as below:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Message;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Tag;
use App\Models\Test;
use App\Models\Permission;
use App\Policies\MessagePolicy;
use App\Policies\RolePolicy;
use App\Policies\UserPolicy;
use App\Policies\TagPolicy;
use App\Policies\TestPolicy;
use App\Policies\PermissionPolicy;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        User::class => UserPolicy::class,
        Role::class => RolePolicy::class,
        Message::class => MessagePolicy::class,
        Tag::class => TagPolicy::class,
        Test::class => TestPolicy::class,
        Permission::class => PermissionPolicy::class,
    ];
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

Also tried

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        'App\Models\User' => 'App\Policies\UserPolicy',
        'App\Models\Role' => 'App\Policies\RolePolicy',
        'App\Models\Message' => 'App\Policies\MessagePolicy',
        'App\Models\Tag' => 'App\Policies\TagPolicy',
        'App\Models\Test' => 'App\Policies\TestPolicy',
        'App\Models\Permission' => 'App\Policies\PermissionPolicy',
    ];
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

[Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authorization) says that, if the Policy matches the naming convention (which does match), then I don't have to register the policies because Laravel would automatically register them.

So I also tried:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
// use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
    ];

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();
    }
}
```

Still none worked.

I'm using Sanctum to authenticate a SPA. So far, everything has been working fine (such as login, logout, and allowing only authenticated users to access resources), but the Policies are not working.

If the user is authenticated, he/she can access and modify any resource, even though the Policy is supposed to not allow it in certain cases.

```js
// will delete the tag with id 1, even though the user making the request
// may not have the permission for it! Since every method in TagPolicy is
// returning false (I set to false for debugging), this shouldn't happen!
axios.delete('/tag/1');
```

Here is `config/auth.php`

```php
<?php
return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],
    'password_timeout' => 10800,
];
```

Any help is appreciated!! I've tried to solve it for days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you've properly registered the policies (and you're correct that there's no need to register a policy when adhering to the naming convention), I believe you also need to [authorize your controller actions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#authorizing-actions-using-policies) to the policies you've created.

The link above outlines all the different ways you can do this, but for explanation I'll include the way to do it via controllers:

```php
public function update(Request $request, Tag $tag)
{
    $this->authorize('update', $tag);

    // The current user can update the tag...
}
```

The authorize method will call your `update` function in the Tag policy, which in this case will return `false`.

I don't know what your `TagController` looks like, but if it is a [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#authorizing-resource-controllers) (using conventional index, show, create, store, etc. functions), you can add the following to the beginning of your `TagController`:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->authorizeResource(Tag::class, 'tag');
}
```

This essentially keeps you from repeating the `$this->authorize(...)` function in each controller action.

If you are already authorizing your actions and this doesn't help, you may need to share your `Routes` and `TagController` so I can investigate further.